# Handle page not found iframe src url without using http service in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, iframe

I am showing an `iframe` for dynamic `url's` which I don't have control over, but when the url is not working my app is crashing. Hence I want to handle the `iframe` `url` when it fails.

I am using an `http` service to handle the `iframe` `src` `url` but am getting a cross browser issue.

Hence please help me to handle this in the `iframe` without using an `http` service or any other solution.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="appController">
    <iframe id="gIframe" ></iframe>
</div>

function appController($scope, $http) {

      $http.get('https://www.google.com/')
        .then(function (response) {         
          document.getElementById("gIframe").setAttribute("src", "https://www.google.com/");
        }, function (response) {
          document.getElementById("gIframe").setAttribute("srcdoc", "<p>Page Not Found</p>");
        });

}
```

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kja78f2h/).